# Laravel 5.4 - Register form, Username lowercase

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I can't find the position and what to change on the register field there is:

Username
First Name
Last Name
Password
Password confirm

Right now the username accepts only lowercase but I want to accept both. Uppercase and lowercase. I also don't want spaces to appear.

I searched in:
RegisterController.php and some js but couldn't fint it. What to change where (Laravel newbie here).

Thanks!

Comment: show some code, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Well, that's the problem I can't find the code.

I want to make to get rid of the controller that only lets users input lowercase usernames.


I can only see this but I am trying to find the function that controlls the username with lowercase only:
      
`code`
protected function create(array $data) {
        return User::create([
                    'username' => $data['username'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users|alpha_dash', 
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users', 
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6', 
        'accepted' => 'required|accepted
    ]);
}
```

In RegisterController look for function name `validator` like above and remove the validation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: protected function validator(array $data) {
        return Validator::make($data, [
                    'username' => 'required|max:255|slug|unique:users',
                    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
                    'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',
                    'accepted' => 'required|accepted',
        ]);


Where is the lowercase function?

Comment: change this to `'username' => 'required|max:255|slug|unique:users` this 'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users

Comment: Thank you very much! So "slug" changes it? 

Do you happen to know that to put in order users can not add spaces to the username?

I do need the validator for other fields. I think I can not simply remove "Validator"

Comment: @createawesomestuff  add `alpha_dash` in the validation . I have updated my answer

Comment: @createawesomestuff yess.

Comment: Perfect! It worked. Now it's accepting lower- and uppercase and also no spaces.

Thank You!

Comment: @createawesomestuff if it solved your problem you can mark this answer as correct.